# Unable to build project for iOS

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Just ran into this problem today using v1.30 and I'm out of ideas on what else to apply.  Funny enough, I can run a debug build on an iOS device and it builds and runs correctly, but attempting to run on a simulator, or build the project in Xcode produces this error.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/n8/srtfdgdx4ggdvqjqp9j3ldwh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.hIAEZA/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirw8LQTg/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: framework not found ObjectBox
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/n8/srtfdgdx4ggdvqjqp9j3ldwh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.hIAEZA/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirw8LQTg/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): Framework not found ObjectBox

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

I've updated the podfiles, ran setup.rb which outputs

```
 ObjectBox Project Setup 

 Looking for project files in the current directory ...
 Found a single project.
 Using "/Users/me/Projects/appName/ios/Runner.xcodeproj"

Target "Runner":

   Skipping target "Runner", build phase "[OBX] Update Sourcery Generated Files" already up to date.

  No changes made to project. 
 ℹ️ If your code generation was not setup properly run with --help to see options

  Please remember to use the .xcworkspace CocoaPods created from now on instead of your project.
```

Output from flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.10.0-1.0.pre.337, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.0-1.0.pre.337 at /Users/me/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 53771aba0c (2 days ago), 2022-01-31 01:15:14 +0530
    • Engine revision fccb9b670d
    • Dart version 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-67.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.10.0-dev.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • D81593D6-5B4A-422C-87BD-8008E7B0AF65 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I've checked files and locations and everything appears to be there, it just appears to not link correctly.  Can anyone shed some insight?

Comment: As you ran setup.rb are you maybe trying to set up ObjectBox for Swift instead of ObjectBox for Dart/Flutter? See https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started for Flutter instructions. For ObjectBox for Dart the iOS libraries ship with the objectbox_flutter_libs package, no setup necessary AFAIK.